# Assymetric Rate Distribution

Tags: options, option-pricing, interest-rates, derivatives, distribution

The pandemic has disavowed any notion of nominal rate distributions to being truncated at 0%.  However, if Central Banks at Debtor nations are conflicted in that they are incented to suppress interest rates (lest their debt service costs skyrocket; and their bond markets crash thereby limiting the ability to raise additional funding through the debt markets), what does this say about the distribution of interest rates and therefore the price of interest rate options?  Is the assumption of normally distributed rates a poor one?

Also, it would seem at some point the loss of confidence in market operations to keep rates and inflation down would imply a much fatter tail than would be implied by a normal distribution (even one that is adjusted to have higher kurtosis).  How is the market adjusting interest rate options to account for these phenomena?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow 100%, but if your question is whether normal distribution assumption for the (forward) rate are made to account for negative rates - then yes. In CHF / EUR at least it has become common for years now to use the Bachelier model for IR option pricing. Sometimes also a shifted version of the lognormal Black is used, where the rate is simply offset by shift $s$ to move it into positive territory again.

Comment: Thanks @KevinT. Yes, this helps tremendously.  Just trying to understand how the markets have corrected for basic assumptions re: interest rates not holding up.  Particularly since it would appear they aren't going to hold with tightening Fed and inflation.

Comment: I think: we've known for decades that FX rates are not normally distributed for a similar reason - when some rates moves "too much" up or down (asymmetric), some CB may start intervening in the markets. While not an exact analogy, I expect modelers to look for similar solutions - try to parameterize the distributions expressed by market views using some observable indications of shape, e.g. risk reversal? By the way, I first encountered negative interest rates breaking bad models in Japan and Brazil (of all places) in early 2000s.